# Windows 10 Disk Usage at 100% but no corresponding process shows in task manager

Tags: windows, malware, windows-10, apt, drivers

Over the past month (possibly more), I have noticed that my laptop (running Windows 10) frequently becomes almost unusably slow, especially after many days of not having turned it on.

I notice that the disk usage in the task manager is at 100% for long periods of time, however this is ridiculous because even the sum of all the processes [that I can see...] could only approach about 5-10% in the generous case.

This is a development machine with 8GB RAM, i7 processor, plenty of space. There are almost no startup programs other than MS default programs (and even there I culled most of the non-essentials out of the startup list). I have also gone through and progressively disabled services such as BITS, Superfetch etc. to no observable effect.

What makes this more suspicious is the pattern in which it occurs - the issue is worst at startup after many days of the computer being physically disconnected and turned off. The startup time is around 3-5 minutes (!) after which the disk runs at 100% usage for a few minutes and then for no explicable reason, suddenly drops down to around 1-5%. All this without showing any processes near full disk usage.

After around a month of investigating this, I am beginning to suspect the involvement of malware, particularly because of the discrepancy in the task manager but also because of how the issue suddenly corrects itself. I should also note that the computer runs AVG Free edition and scans of the computer and anti-rootkit are coming up clean. That being said, I want to pursue the possibility that this could be malware connecting and updating itself, or even worse, exfiltrating data [or even worse, chewing my disk to encrypt my files while telling me everything is OK]?

Currently I do not observe an irregular amount of network traffic which would support the exfiltration theory, however it is also possible to hide this from the task manager / wireshark using a rogue driver.

I have a number of questions:

1. Does this pattern of behavior fit any known malware / APT threats?
2. Supposing I were to continue this into the forensics direction, what further steps could be taken to investigate and validate the drivers on the machine?
3. What steps beyond task manager can I take in order to monitor and identify the process which is actually responsible for the 100% disk usage?
4. Are there any legitimate / Windows reasons this might be occurring and if so, how can I narrow down and isolate the problematic components?

Comment: disk usage or CPU usage is 100%?

Comment: Disk usage, CPU is fine

Comment: sounds like typical anti-malware behaviour - a scan is being triggered

Comment: No record of such scans exist, and my antivirus is not set to perform any startup scans of any kind.

Comment: Download [Process Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) and see what it says. It is more complete than task manager.

Comment: My boss asked me to check out their computer for the same thing this week. I ran Process Hacker 2, windirstat and ccleaner on his machine. Through windirstat I discovered he had large generating log files. Process Hacker in detailed show me what services were keeping his harddisk busy. Through those details I was able to identify and disable legitimate but problematic programs. Ccleaner helped remove a bunch of additional unneeded logs and temp files. These three steps freed up nearly 50 gigs in 5 minutes as well as alleviate his HD traffic.

Comment: The drive may be failing. If it goes to 100% with no or little actual reads/writes then that is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Do not rely on task manager as it will only show you what is running in Windows. You need to be looking at **Resource and Performance Monitor** (`perfmon.exe`) which will give you a better idea of exactly what is using resources. Hyper-v for instance will not show in Task Manager but will show in Resource Monitor.

When you see 100% usage, sort by write. If you done see anything huge, check read.

How old is your HDD and what is the model of it?

Comment: To whoever downvoted:
What steps beyond task manager can I take in order to monitor and identify the process which is actually responsible for the 100% disk usage?

That question I have answered.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://security.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/66621)

Comment: This does answer question #3 (and likely will point the OP to the true answer). Unfortunately, #3 is the non-security portion of the question. I'll let the community decide (I'm a mod), but I hope that this answer survives.

Comment: Ahh. I missed the Resource Monitor reference despite multiple readings. It's sort of subtle. Good catch @schroeder.

Comment: Tim, perhaps adding a resmon link would make the answer stronger.

Comment: perfmon.exe didn't really take me to a UI that would easily give me what I wanted. **perfmon.exe /res** did though.

Comment: I have similar problem and resmon does not show any process that could be thrashing it, yet I hear the sound of hdd doing some extensive io.